# How to fill an array from several textboxes?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, textbox

I am trying to fill an array from several textboxes, then calculate with the values in the array.

I have the following code, but don't know why it doesn't work. Explained in the code:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] temperaturen = new double[6];

    temperaturen[0] = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
   
    MessageBox.Show(temperaturen[0].ToString()); //the messagebox is just to test if 
                                                 //it works
}
```

The above code works, but it stops working after I add more values from more textboxes:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] temperaturen = new double[6];
    
    temperaturen[0] = double.Parse(textBox1.Text); //now it stops working and gives 
    temperaturen[1] = double.Parse(textBox2.Text); //the following error:
    temperaturen[2] = double.Parse(textBox3.Text); //format exceptions was unhandled.
    temperaturen[3] = double.Parse(textBox4.Text);
    temperaturen[4] = double.Parse(textBox5.Text);
    temperaturen[5] = double.Parse(textBox6.Text);
    temperaturen[6] = double.Parse(textBox7.Text);

    MessageBox.Show(temperaturen[0].ToString());
}
```

Does anybody know if parsing from textbox is the right way of doing this whatsoever? and why this does not work?

Comment: Did you put valid textual representations of a `double` into all these textboxes?

Comment: likely some of your textboxes do not have a double into them. Do note that your question does not have a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: `new double[7];` - note, that you have **7** text boxes

Comment: I'd use `double.TryParse` instead. You can never trust user input.

Comment: @cleptus the problem was input in the textboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Please note, that you have **7** textboxes, not `6`, so you should declare `new double[7]`.
To avoid  such errors, let's query with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

double[] temperaturen = new TextBox[] {
  textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, 
  textBox4, textBox5, textBox6,
  textBox7 }
  .Select(box => double.TryParse(box.Text, out var value) ? value : double.NaN)
  .ToArray();
```

Note, that text box can have text which is *not* a valid floating point value (say, `"bla-bla-bla"`),
I put `double.NaN` (**N**ot **a** **N**umber) in this case.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. i already figured out the other error, which was a index error. so i changed the array to [7].    The assignment calls for error handling with try catch, so I will go that route.

Answer (score 1):

What actually solved the problem is:
Adding a try catch, and changing the array to have 7 values.

---

The final code, fully functioning.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal[] temperaturen = new decimal[7];//the array

    try // try block
    {
        temperaturen[0] = decimal.Parse(txtZondag.Text);//parsing input 
        temperaturen[1] = decimal.Parse(txtMaandag.Text);//from 
        temperaturen[2] = decimal.Parse(txtDinsdag.Text);//textboxes
        temperaturen[3] = decimal.Parse(txtWoensdag.Text);
        temperaturen[4] = decimal.Parse(txtDonderdag.Text);
        temperaturen[5] = decimal.Parse(txtVrijdag.Text);
        temperaturen[6] = decimal.Parse(txtZaterdag.Text);
        decimal temp = 10.2m;//decimal temp for calculations

        decimal uitkomst1 = 0.0m;//decimal for sum.
        uitkomst1 = temperaturen[0] - temp;//calculation
        textBox8.Text = uitkomst1.ToString();

        decimal uitkomst2 = 0;
        uitkomst2 = temperaturen[1] - temp;
        textBox9.Text = uitkomst2.ToString();

        decimal uitkomst3 = 0;
        uitkomst3 = temperaturen[2] - temp;
        textBox10.Text = uitkomst3.ToString();

        decimal uitkomst4 = 0.0m;
        uitkomst4 = temperaturen[3] = temp;
        textBox11.Text = uitkomst4.ToString();

        decimal uitkomst5 = 0;
        uitkomst5 = temperaturen[4] - temp;
        textBox12.Text = uitkomst5.ToString();

        decimal uitkomst6 = 0;
        uitkomst6 = temperaturen[5] - temp;
        textBox13.Text = uitkomst6.ToString();

        decimal uitkomst7 = 0;
        uitkomst7 = temperaturen[6] - temp;
        textBox14.Text = uitkomst7.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)//catch block
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrecte invoer!  " + exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a [Self-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You can even [Accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) after 48 hours. Also, consider upvoting 'other' answers if they were were helpful in answering your question. "If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an acceptable answer. If it provides some value give it an upvote. If it needs clarification add a comment." See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not SOLID, meaning that it doesn't follow the guidelines of the Solid principle. If you are not familiar with SOLID, consider to read [some background information about SOLID](https://codesigningstore.com/software-development-best-practice-for-programmers)

For instance, your code has more than one Responsibility. This principle states that each class should have a single purpose or responsibility. This helps reduce bugs by:

- Simplifying the code,
- Making testing easier, and
- Allowing for more modularity (i.e., the ability to reuse and combine code).

In your case: you need a class that can read the temperature from somewhere. This can be from a text box, or from the internet, a digital thermometer, anything:

```
interface IThermometer
{
    double ReadTemperature();
}

class TextBoxThermometer : IThermometer
{
    public TextBox TextBox {get; set;}

    public double ReadTemperature()
    {
        // TODO: add some error checking: null textbox, no proper value in the textbox, etc.
        return Double.Parse(this.TextBox.Text);
    }
}
```

This class is easy to create, easy to test, and easy to maintain: if you want a decimal as temperature, the changes will be minimal.

Once you've got this class, and created unit tests for them, you can be certain that the class is working correctly, for any TextBox that you attach to this class.

Apparently you don't have one Thermometer, you've got a collection of Thermometers. From each Thermometer you can read the temperature:

```
class ThermometerCollection : IReadOnlyCollection<IThermometer>
{
    public List<IThermometer> Thermometers {get; set;}

    // TODO: implement IReadOnlyCollection<IThermometer>

    public double ReadTemperatur(int thermometerIndex)
    {
        // TODO: check validity of thermometerIndex
        return this.Thermometers[thermometerIndex].ReadTemperature();
    }
}
```

The thermometer collection is also a fairly simple class with functions with only one or two lines. Easy to understand, Easy to test, easy to maintain. If desired you can even have different types of thermometers in the collection: one that reads from a text box, another that reads from the internet.

Because you've unit tested the class, you can be certain that it works with all kinds of IThermometers.

Inside your form:

```
private IReadOnlyCollection<IThermometer> Thermometers {get;}

public MyForm() // constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Thermometers = new ThermometerCollection
    {
        Thermometers = new List<IThermometer>()
        {
            new TextBoxThermometer() {TextBox = this.TextBox1},
            new TextBoxThermometer() {TextBox = this.TextBox2},
            new TextBoxThermometer() {TextBox = this.TextBox3},
            new TextBoxThermometer() {TextBox = this.TextBox4},
            new TextBoxThermometer() {TextBox = this.TextBox5},
            new TextBoxThermometer() {TextBox = this.TextBox6},
        },
    }
}
```

Now your form has one ThermometerCollection with six thermometers. For users of these thermometers, it is not important how they get their temperature. They might read them from a text box, but if in future you decide to read the temperature from the internet, changes in your form will be minimal. Remember: because you've got unit tests for your TextBoxThermometer you can be sure that this type of Thermometer works flawless.

Now that you've decoupled the Thermometer from where it gets the temperature, in your form you can write methods to read the temperature

```
public double ReadTemperature(int thermometerIndex)
{
    return this.ThermometerCollection.ReadTemperature(thermometerIndex);
}
```

Again a one liner method. Note that this is a method in your Form, so it is fairly difficult to unit test. But since you have tested the ThermometerCollection thoroughly, you hardly miss the test.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ProcessTemperatures();
    // TODO: do other things that must be done when button1 is clicked
}

public void ProcessTemperatures()
{
    // Read the temperatures, and process them:
    ICollection<double> measuredTemperatures = Enumerable.Range(1,6)
        .Select(thermometerIndex => this.ReadTemperature(thermometerIndex)
        .ToList();

    this.ProcessTemperatures(measuredTemperatures);
}

public void ProcessTemperatures(ICollection<double> measuredTemperatures)
{
    // TODO: do what you wanted to do with your measured temperatures
}
```

I've decoupled the button click from the processing. If later you decide that you want to do something different if the button is clicked, changes will be minimal. Also, if you want to add a menu item that will also process the temperatures: the procedure will be a one liner.

### Summary

Because I made methods that only have one specific task, you have methods that are easy to understand, easy to unit test, simple to change and maintain, simple to reuse.

Because I separated your from from the notion of Thermometers, you can reuse the thermometers in a different form. You have unit tested the Thermometer classes, so you can be certain that it will also work if you want 10 Thermometers.

Because I separated the Thermometer from where it gets its data from, it is easy to use a different type of Thermometer, for instance one that reads from a cell in a table, or from the internet. Users of your Thermometer class won't notice the difference.